# Lumen 6.0 assertSessionHasErrors() method doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, lumen

I'm using Lumen 6.0 for building a project and now I have to write some tests. I'm trying to make sure that the validation errors exist while calling an endpoint however the method named **assertSessionHasErrors** does not exist.

```
 public function an_http_call_must_be_valid()
{
    $response = $this->json('POST', $this->endpoint, [
        'referrer' => 'web'
    ], $this->validHeaders);
    $response->assertSessionHasErrors();
}
```

Output of the command:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
 1) EmailNotificationTest::an_http_call_must_be_valid
 Error: Call to undefined method EmailNotificationTest::assertSessionHasErrors()
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the assertJsonStructure method to check if the validation error message exists in the response.

```
$this->json('POST', $this->endpoint, [
        'referrer' => 'web'
    ], $this->validHeaders)->assertJsonStructure(['errors'=>[]]]);
```

Comment: It worked, but can you please mention where is this documentation?